# Removing test database during unit test cleanup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, mstest, sql-server-2017, dac

I'm working on some automated tests (using MSTest) that create a unique database for each test case, isolating each test from the results of the previous tests (and test runs). I'm using the Microsoft DACFx tools to accomplish this. How can I remove the test database during test cleanup, so I don't rack up a huge collection? The SQL Server instance is running on `localhost`.

I looked through the [DACFx documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn702988.aspx) and couldn't find any way to remove an entire database.

This is the code I use to create the database, and it would be nice if there were a way to also delete it in code, rather than by executing a SQL script:

```
using (var dacpac = DacPackage.Load(path)) {
    instance.Deploy(dacpac, databaseName, upgradeExisting: true);
}
```

Comment: it looks like early 2012 they dropped support for "drop database" in DACFx? See this SQL Server blog article by Bob Beauchemin here: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/dacfx-3-0-the-new-programming-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do exactly the same with creating a Test database in `TestInitialize` and then removing it during `TestCleanup`. For me though, the database is always called 'UnitTesting'. You could use some string substitution if your unique names are generated in C# code

In `TestCleanup` I execute this script

```
USE [master];

DECLARE @kill varchar(8000) = '';  
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), session_id) + ';'   FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE database_id  = db_id('UnitTesting')

EXEC(@kill);

/****** Object:  Database [UnitTesting]    Script Date: 12/05/2018 23:06:16 ******/
USE [master]

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = 'UnitTesting')
    DROP DATABASE [UnitTesting]
```

You may also want to run this script during `TestInitialize` to make sure any incomplete runs don't affect the next Test Method

Comment: Thanks, I may need to use that, but I was hoping not to have to use a script. I'll update my question to specify that.

Comment: How are you running this script? I found the `kill` parts didn't work, since I get an error stating I can't kill the active connection. But just using the part after the comment worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I am running standard C# code to execute...using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection) ... using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand) ... command.ExecuteNonQuery(); It's a block of code I have used in numerous different Unit Test projects all under MSTest, I have dbo_owner rights on the server